# python - check if nan float in dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, numpy, dictionary, nan

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tia.bbg.datamgr as dm
mgr = dm.BbgDataManager()

bb_yearb4 = "2016-12-30"
bb_today = "2017-09-22"

indices = [list of indices]
sids_index = mgr[indices]
df_idx = sids_index.get_historical('PX_LAST', bb_yearb4, bb_today)

nan = np.nan

price_test = {}
for index in indices:
    price_test["{0}".format(index)] = df_idx.loc[bb_today][index]
```

The output shows multiple nan float values:

```
In [1]: price_test.values()
Out[1]: [nan, nan, nan, 47913.199999999997, nan, 1210.3299999999999, nan]
```

However, testing for nan shows false:

```
In [2]: nan in price_test.values()
Out[2]: False
```

What is the correct way to test this?

Comment: `np.nan in price_test.values()`

Comment: @Wen: They're already doing that, and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

NaN is weird, because NaN != NaN. There's a good reason for that, but it still breaks `in` checks and everything else that assumes normal `==` behavior.

Check for NaN with NaN-specific checks, like `numpy.isnan`:

```
any(np.isnan(val) for val in d.values())
```

or in a non-NumPy context,

```
any(math.isnan(val) for val in d.values())
```

Comment: Maybe `math.isnan` instead of `val != val` ?

Comment: @JonClements: Oh, huh, that's a thing. I forgot the `math` module actually has an `isnan`.

Comment: @piRSquared: The NaN in their dict isn't the same object as `np.nan`. Python does an `is` check before `==` here, which is throwing you off.

Answer (score 0):

This dictionary comprehension helps extract a dict with NaN's (unlike `np.isnan(v)`, which raises an error):

```
{k:v for k,v in my_dict.items() if v is np.nan}
```

Then you can check for `len()` of the resulting dict being positive if boolean info is sufficient.